# Correct use of coordinates to plot surface data with Plotly?

Tags: python, plot, plotly-python, surface

Suppose I have an array `X` of x values and `Y` of y values, and a dictionary `results`, such that `results[x][y]` accesses a z value. How would I construct a `z` variable do correctly match the coordinates that are generating it?

For instance:

```
X = [0,2,3]
Y = [-1,-2,-3]
results = {x:{y: x/y for y in Y} for x in X}

Z = np.array([[results[x][y] for y in Y] for x in X ])
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=Z, x=X, y=Y)])
fig.update_layout(title='Plot', autosize=False,
                  width=500, height=500,
                  margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))
fig.update_layout(scene = dict(xaxis_title='X',
                    yaxis_title='Y'
                              )
                 )
fig.show()
```

gives a wrong graph:

[image]

How does this coordinate system work? Doing `Z = np.array([[results[x][y] for x in X] for y in Y ])` gives the correct result, but this doesn't make sense to me. Why is `x` the second coordinate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

The reason you're getting weird results is due to how computers represent matrices, which is by rows and columns where the "first" element, at the index `0, 0` is at the top-left corner, whereas it's more intuitive to be thinking of the XY-plane where bottom-left corner is the origin, which is the standard way to view graphs in mathematics.

### Solution

First, by taking full advantage of numpy, you can compute `z` much quicker via `np.divide.outer()`. This gives the correct result for `z` without the unnecessary `dict` and nested comprehension (and will be WAY more efficient for larger arrays).

```py
x = np.array([0, 2, 3])
y = np.array([-1, -2, -3])
z = np.divide.outer(x, y)
```

Now since computers see matrices differently than what is intuitively viewed as `z = f(x, y)`, you need to plot *the transpose* of `z`:

```py
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z.T, x=x, y=y)])
```

Result:

[image]

### Slightly more detailed explanation

If we orient the plot such that we're looking at the x-axis oriented how we normally view it on 2D graphs (increasing from left to right):

[image]

You can see that on the left edge of the surface, `z`, all the values are zero. But notice how `z` is represented as an array:

```py
>>> np.round(z, 2)
array([[-0.  , -0.  , -0.  ],
       [-2.  , -1.  , -0.67],
       [-3.  , -1.5 , -1.  ]])
```

If you transpose `z`, you'll see that the "left" edge of the matrix is all zeros:

```py
>>> np.round(z.T, 2)
array([[-0.  , -2.  , -3.  ],
       [-0.  , -1.  , -1.5 ],
       [-0.  , -0.67, -1.  ]])
```

This hopefully helps shine some light on the difference between xy-coordinates and the row-column representation of arrays. Something else to note is that the y-axis is "reversed" in the reoriented plot above. This is because the top row of a matrix is considered the "first" element, but in a normal xy-coordinate system, the y-axis increases going vertically (i.e., starting at the bottom).

### Using a meshgrid for multivariate functions

Something you can do to avoid having to transpose `z` is using `np.meshgrid()`:

```py
>>> x_coords, y_coords = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing="xy")
>>> z = x_coords / y_coords
>>> z
array([[-0.  , -2.  , -3.  ],
       [-0.  , -1.  , -1.5 ],
       [-0.  , -0.67, -1.  ]])
```

Notice now that `z` is already in the proper format for plotting as a surface. Note that this also gets rid of the necessity of `np.outer()`. Using a meshgrid is also much better for evaluating arbitrary functions on a coordinate grid.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. You explained the problem clearly by pointing out the way the data is interpreted by the machine. I was actually aware of the broadcasting capabilities of NumPy and how they could circumvent this issue. However, in my real-world application, there is no possibility for vectorizing/broadcasting, and the data needs to be accessed by that dictionary.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so, please go ahead and accept it so that your question can be removed from the unanswered queue! Glad I could help.